# Simplify the Expression $\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \binom{n}{k}}i^{k}3^{k-n} $

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I should simplify the following expression (for a complex number):
$$\sum _{ k=0 }^{ n }{ \binom{n}{k}}i^{k}3^{k-n} $$

The solution is $(i+\frac{1}{3})^n$,but i don't quite get the steps. If would be nice if someone could explain.

---

> The Binomial Theorem:
>   $(x+y)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^{k}$

Comment: $3^{k-n}=\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n-k}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}i^k 3^{k-n}
  = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}i^k \left(3^{-1}\right)^{n-k}
  = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}i^k \left(1/3\right)^{n-k}
  = (i+1/3)^n
$$

Answer (score 2):

Just use that 
$$3^{k-n}=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-k}$$
Then you have exactly the binomial theorem and hence it is 
$$(i+\frac{1}{3})^n$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Set $x = \frac {1}{3}$, $ y = i$.

Comment: thats the solution which is given, how should that help the OP ?